# Two forms of test statistics in likelihood ratio tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing

From Bickel and Doksum's Mathematical Statistics

[image]

[image]

I was wondering what "$\Theta_0$ is of smaller dimension than $\Theta = \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1$" means?
Note: In the original text, "$\theta_0$" is a typo and should be $\Theta_0$.

Why when "$p(x, \theta)$ is continuous in $\theta$ and $\Theta_0$ is of smaller dimension that $\Theta = \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1$", then $L(x)= \lambda(x)$?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

$\Theta_0$: $\theta$ = 0, here $\theta$ has dimension zero, as it is fixed.

$\Theta_1$: $\theta$ $\neq$ 0 .

Let $\Theta = \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1 $,  here $\Theta$ is one dimensional, it can be any real number.

So "$\Theta_0$ is of smaller dimension that $\Theta = \Theta_0 \cup \Theta_1$" just means $\Theta$ is bigger (or say, it contains) $\Theta_0$.

Comment: Thanks! (1) So dimension means the dimensions of the vector space $\Theta_0$ and of $\Theta$? It doesn't mean the number of components in the vector $\theta$? (2) Why the above condition and continuity of the likelihood function in $\theta$ imply $L(x)= \lambda(X)$?

Comment: Tim, $\Theta_0$ and $\Theta$ are usually not vector spaces: they are real manifolds. When $\Theta_0$ has smaller dimension than $\Theta$ and $p$ is continuous in $\theta$, then the supremum attained over $\Theta$ cannot differ from that attained over $\Theta_1$: this is an elementary implication of continuity.